# Interpolation Search Implementation on Ruby Infinite Loop

Tags: ruby, binary-search, linear-interpolation

I have just learnt how to do an interpolation search but am having issues with its implementation on Ruby. I keep having infinite loops with either the lower bound or the upper bound being close to the searched number but the lower bound doesn't touch the upper bound for a exit condition of the method.

```html
def exist?(id)
 lower = 0
 upper = $employee_list.length - 1
 while lower <= upper
  rise = upper - lower
  run = $employee_list[upper] - $employee_list[lower]
  x = id - $employee_list[lower]
  middle = (rise.to_f / run.to_f * x.to_f + lower.to_f).floor
  if id == $employee_list[middle]
   return true
  elsif id < $employee_list[middle]
   upper = middle - 1
  else
   lower = middle + 1
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Is `$employee_list` sorted?

Comment: Yes it is! And your code works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Notes

- If `lower` is equal to `upper`, `run` is 0 and you divide by 0.
- There's no exit condition in your code. There's no reason `lower` than `upper`, so it loops infinitely.

## Solution

I mixed your code and the one mentionned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) and it seems to work fine :

```
def exist?(array, key)
  lower = 0
  upper = array.length - 1
  while array[upper] != array[lower] && key >= array[lower] && key <= array[upper]
    middle = lower + ((key - array[lower]) * (upper - lower) / (array[upper] - array[lower]))
    if key > array[middle]
      lower = middle + 1
    elsif key < array[middle]
      upper = middle - 1
    else
      return true
    end
  end
  key == array[lower]
end

exist?($employee_list, id)
```

You could also return the index or `nil` instead of `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks! Can I replace the `key == array[lower]` with `return false`?

Also, is there a faster algorithm than interpolation search? My code runs at about 2 seconds for an array with a million elements. There are others that did at half a second and I wonder what algorithms they are using.

Comment: I'm not sure about deleting `key==array[lower]`. I tried with a large array and looked for every element, and couldn't find any where `key==array[lower]`. I'm not sure I tested every possibility, though. Interpolation search works best when the values are spread out uniformly in the array. Also, https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch might be faster, simply because it is written in C.